# deploying another war in embedded jetty

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, embedded-jetty, embedded-tomcat-7

I am a no bee to stack over flow. Apologize if i broke any rules.

I can start jetty embedded server but i want to deploy a war before starting the server in the same program. i kept my external war in another folder and i tried with the below code

```java
final Server server = new Server();
    final WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setContextPath("/");
    final URL url = Main.class.getResource("war1.war");
    final String a = url.getPath();
    System.out.println(a);
    webapp.setWar(a);
    webapp.setExtractWAR(true);
    webapp.setCopyWebInf(true);
    server.setHandler(webapp);

    server.start();
    server.join();
```

This is giving a error. please guide me if i did anything wrong.

```
2013-11-27 12:59:01.992:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,[file:/C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Temp/JettyContext1841794772027580678/webinf/, file:/C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Temp/JettyContext1841794772027580678/webapp/]},/C:/Users/admiin/Documents/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/JettyRunner/target/classes/war1.war
MultiException[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspSourceDependent, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspSourceDependent, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspSourceDependent]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:718)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1238)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at Main.main(Main.java:39)
```

please let me know if i need to do anything else. My goal is to deploy a external war with a embedded tomcat/jetty server (any webserver).

Comment: on which os ur doing this ??

Comment: Update your question with the following details.  which version of jetty? what version of the servlet spec? do you have any special requirements (such as JNDI or JSP or Annotation scanning)?